# Notepad ++ как сделать чтобы скобочки, кавычки и прочие символы сами закрывались

Tags: notepad++

Notepad ++ как сделать чтобы скобочки, кавычки и прочие символы сами закрывались

Answer (score 2):

В поле Опции=>настройки=>автозавершение=>Заказная пара проставить 2 кавычки в обоих столбцах (откр. и закр.). Для скобок там есть свой чекбокс отдельный